# Stochastic Gradient on the Simplex

Tags: maximum-likelihood, markov-process, likelihood, gradient-descent

I have a probability density function defined over $x_1,...,x_K$ with a simplex constraint $\sum_{k=1}^K x_k = 1$.

I'm trying to perform stochastic gradient descent on this density. I know I can keep the simplex constraint by setting $x_K = 1 - (x_1 + ... + x_{K-1})$, but this makes the gradient quite nasty.

I was wondering if there's an easier way to make sure the simplex constraint is adhered to. For example perhaps using an idea similar to Lagrange multipliers and introducing a new variable $\lambda$ which I perform stochastic gradient descent on as well?

Comment: Have you had a look at the [barrier function approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_function#Logarithmic_barrier_function)?